# Find the elements between matching elements in two lists

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have two lists of words called *query* and *sentence*. What I want to find is, for each pair of consecutive words in the *query*, a list of all the words between those two in the *sentence*. Also, if the first word of the *query* is not the first word of the *sentence*, the result should include a list with all the words in the *sentence* up to that one (and the same goes for the last word in the *query*).

So for example, if the *query* and the *sentence* looked like this:

```
query = ["like", "with"]
sentence = ["I", "like", "coffee", "with", "sugar", "and", "milk"]
```

then the result should be:

```
result = [["I"], ["coffee"],["sugar", "and", "milk"]]
```

However, there might be more than one way to make this match, depending on the *sentence* and *query*. For example:

```
query = ["bear", "my"]
sentence = ["I", "cannot", "bear", "when", "my", "bear", "leaves", "my", "house"]
```

In this case, there are many valid results:

```
result1 = [["I", "cannot"], ["when"], ["bear", "leaves", "my", "house"]]
result2 = [["I", "cannot"], ["when", "my", "bear", "leaves"], ["house"]]
result3 = [["I", "cannot", "bear", "when", "my"], ["leaves"], ["house"]]
```

So, what I need is a list of all the possible results for a given *sentence* and *query*. I've been trying to come up with a solution for a while now, but I can't work out how to find all possible combinations without making a mess of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exercise in non-determinism, which is modeled by the `[]` monad.

Start by writing a function

```
foo :: String -> [String] -> [([String], [String])]
```

that can split `sentence` into exactly two parts based on a given word. That is,

```
foo "bear" sentence == [
  (["I", "cannot"], ["when", "my", "bear", "leaves", "my", "house"]),
  (["I", "cannot", "bear", "when", "my"], ["leaves", "my", "house"]),
]
```

Given a list of split words, you recursively split the second list using the next split word.

```
do_it [] _ = []
do_it (q:qs) words = do
       (x, y) <- foo q words
       return (x : do_it qs words)
```

Comment: I like your idea, but I think there's a problem with it. For each possible result, you can only use each word in the query one time, and you have to use them in order. With your solution, each word in the query could be used many times, and in any order

Comment: Oh, ok, that was my original thought, but then I misread your sample results to think the more general case applied.

Comment: It would be good to add which Complexity does this have? But it's a really good approach, I think that constraint could be accomplished just by ordering the final result don't you think?

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco I think it's fixed (this isn't tested, as I haven't done the harder part of defining `foo` myself).

Comment: The complexity is something like `O(n^d)`, where `n` is the length of the list and `d` the number of query words. But more importantly, that's probably optimal, that's probably how many elements are in the output. You can't go faster than it would take to enumerate the result.

Comment: I think that's definitely it! Thanks a lot for the help.